# Creating your own HTTP web services for XMPP

Tags: .net, web-services, windows-phone-7, xmpp

Given the many issues with sockets and XMPP in WP7 (and WP7.5) I thought of doing something to make this a better world... but then came the catch, I don't much about web servers (actually not much about the web in general).

Note that I'm not asking about web servers nor security nor hardware nor hosting but actual code. Also I don't intend for this to be globally used service, but rather a fee-free-to-use-under-your-own-risk service.

Question is, What would I need to do to create a web service that could act as a layer in between wp7+ push notifications and XMPP? I intend to do this in .NET (C# or Visual Basic, whichever). The main goal of this is to provide the means to create a service for a gTalk client that could work over push, but it could be generalized to support any other XMPP service (if the latter doesn't become to much of a trouble).

Comment: So you want gTalk client to use HTTP(S) or do you want Web Service to understand XMPP or ?   I am not following.  But it sounds interesting.

Comment: I want a gTalk client that can keep on working even when on background on WP7, and for what I've read that's not possible due to limitations on the XMPP WP7 implementation. If both would work then the first one sounds easier though.

Comment: I echo what @Blam said, it does sound interesting. Just as a side note, once you get closer to actually deploying it. You'll want to remove the Push notification limit and for that you have to [Authentice your web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941099(v=vs.92).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the socket problem is, but if you're looking to tunnel XMPP over HTTP, use BOSH ([XEP-0124](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0124.html)/[XEP-0206](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html)).  One approach would be to use a BOSH proxy like [Punjab](https://github.com/twonds/punjab).

Comment: The problem is that Wp7 does not allow persistent sockets. Whenever your app goes in background WP7.x closes your socket. It also does not allow application to continue running in the background. This is why BOSH and sockets work only as long as your app is active.
This is the reason why many developers are writing XMPP <==> Push servers.

Comment: @Alex do you have an idea as to how can I write that server?

Comment: The architecture is as Joe suggested. Only instead of HTTP/BOSH you have to use Push.